# Why can't I use record selectors with an existentially quantified type?

Tags: haskell, record, existential-type

When using Existential types, we have to use a pattern-matching syntax for extracting the `forall`ed value. We can't use the ordinary record selectors as functions. GHC reports an error and suggest using pattern-matching with this definition of `yALL`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data ALL = forall a. Show a => ALL { theA :: a }
-- data ok

xALL :: ALL -> String
xALL (ALL a) = show a
-- pattern matching ok

-- ABOVE: heaven
-- BELOW: hell

yALL :: ALL -> String
yALL all = show $ theA all
-- record selector failed
```

---

```
forall.hs:11:19:
    Cannot use record selector `theA' as a function due to escaped type variables
    Probable fix: use pattern-matching syntax instead
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `theA all'
    In the expression: show $ theA all
    In an equation for `yALL': yALL all = show $ theA all
```

Some of my data take more than 5 elements. It's hard to maintain the code if I
use pattern-matching:

```
func1 (BigData _ _ _ _ elemx _ _) = func2 elemx
```

Is there a good method to make code like that maintainable or to wrap it up so that I can use some kind of selectors?

Comment: Hint: What would be the type of `theA`?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: do you mean using existential syntax in yALL ? how?

Comment: Basically, the answer is that it _doesn't_ have an expressible type, so you need pattern matching to get a workable type.

Comment: Or more accurately, it would have the type `exists a. Show a => ALL -> a`, were Haskell to have first-class existential types.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use record syntax in pattern matching,

```
func1 BigData{ someField = elemx } = func2 elemx
```

works and is much less typing for huge types.

Comment: Great Answer! I just found it later: data B { x :: Int, y :: Int} ; fun B{..} = x + y; that can be an alternative.

Answer (score 22):

Existential types work in a more elaborate manner than regular types.  GHC is (rightly) forbidding you from using `theA` as a function.  But imagine there was no such prohibition.  What type would that function have?  It would have to be something like this:

```
-- Not a real type signature!
theA :: ALL -> t  -- for a fresh type t on each use of theA; t is an instance of Show
```

To put it very crudely, `forall` makes GHC "forget" the type of the constructor's arguments; all that the type system knows is that this type is an instance of `Show`.  So when you try to extract the value of the constructor's argument, there is no way to recover the original type.

What GHC does, behind the scenes, is what the comment to the fake type signature above says—each time you pattern match against the `ALL` constructor, the variable bound to the constructor's value is assigned a unique type that's guaranteed to be different from every other type.  Take for example this code:

```
case ALL "foo" of
    ALL x -> show x
```

The variable `x` gets a unique type that is distinct from every other type in the program and cannot be matched with any type variable.  These unique types are not allowed to escape to the top level—which is the reason why `theA` cannot be used as a function.

Comment: Generally, you can think of an existential type as a dependent tuple, where the first element is a type (`*`) and the second is a value of that type - `Σ[ a : * ] a`. The problem is, that when you attempt to write a type signature for a projection of the second element of the tuple, you need to know the value of the first element. This cannot be expressed in Haskell. If you have dependently typed language you can write it as (using Agda notation): `(x : Σ[ a : * ] a) → fst x`.

Comment: +1 This explains the error message "Cannot use record selector `theA' as a function **due to escaped type variables**"