# Can I coerce an existentially quantified argument in a type constructor?

Tags: haskell, types, gadt, existential-type

I have a data type whose (single) constructor contains an existentially quantified type variable:

```
data LogEvent = forall a . ToJSON a =>
            LogEvent { logTimestamp     :: Date
                     , logEventCategory :: Category
                     , logEventLevel    :: LogLevel
                     , logThreadId      :: ThreadId
                     , logPayload       :: a
                     }
```

When I wrote that type initially I hid the polymorphic payload because all I was interested in at the time was outputting to some file/stream. But now I want to do more interesting things for which I need to observe the actual type of `a`.

I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192663/why-cant-i-use-record-selectors-with-an-existentially-quantified-type) and other readings that existentially quantified type variables are unique upon each instantiation. However, given type is `ToJSON a` I can something like the following (pseudo-code):

```
 let x :: Result Foo = fromJSON $ toJSON (logPayload event)
```

It seems odd to be able to convert to and from JSON with a more precise type, although I can understand the rationale behind that.

So how can I rewrite that type to allow to extract `logPayload` if I know its type? I

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is similar to the [existential typeclass](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) (anti-)pattern.  This existential magic is equivalent to

```
data LogEvent = 
        LogEvent { logTimestamp     :: Date
                 , logEventCategory :: Category
                 , logEventLevel    :: LogLevel
                 , logThreadId      :: ThreadId
                 , logPayload       :: Aeson.Value
                 }
```

but this communicates more clearly what your structure represents.  You should not expect anything from your existential structure that you would not expect from this.

On the other hand, if you *do* know `logPayload`'s type, then you should encode that knowledge at the type level by moving the type variable out:

```
data LogEvent a = ...
```

At which point a value of type `LogPayload Foo` represents your knowledge of the payload's type.  Then if you are so inclined you could define

```
data ALogEvent = forall a. ToJSON a => ALogEvent (LogEvent a)
```

for when you don't know it.  In practice I have very rarely seen the need for both of these to exist, but maybe you have a use case for it.

If you know the type of `logPayload` at run-time, but cannot track the payload at compile time for some reason, perhaps you could add a `Typeable a` constraint to your existential so that you can cast without resorting to `unsafeCoerce`... in case you made a mistake you won't corrupt your whole program bizarrely.

Comment: I am using an existential wrapper here because events are passed down a `Chan LogEvent` to log them asynchronously: A separate thread reads the event and handles it. I of course initially tried to make the `LogEvent` type parameterised with its payload type but then I don't gain anything because the consumer at the other end of the channel can still not observe the type of the event.

Comment: If the consumer needs to observe the type of event, I would recommend an algebraic type.  That is, unless it treats all events uniformly save a special case or two, in which case Typeable is probably right

Comment: Yes but this means tying the `LogEvent` type to the logged events, something I wanted to avoid but obviously will not be able to defer anymore :-) This is not library code so I don't care too much although this means making log module dependent on every logged type of the system, which sucks a little bit...

Comment: @insitu, if the logger needs to observe the event type, the logger already has this dependency does it not?

Comment: Sure :-) But not on ALL the logged types. To this you might answer: provide typed constructor for those types you need to observe and you would probably be right! Let's try that...

Answer (score 2):

You might consider giving `Data.Typeable` a shot; throw in a `Typeable a` constraint into your existential type, and then if you can correctly guess the hidden type you can get the value back under that type.  See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/sacundim/8511f98d6173d8d46533) for a toy example.

Do note that this technique sacrifices some amount of type safety—if you start putting in another type inside `LogEvent` that you didn't before you may break users of the type that assume that they're successfully handling every subcase.  Unlike with algebraic types, dynamics and casts mean the compiler can't help you prove exhaustiveness.

Comment: Following luqui's comment I have started to go down that route but then hit a wall:     Cannot eta-reduce to an instance of form
      instance (...) => Typeable Command
    In the data instance declaration for ‘Command’ The types I want to log are actually instances of a type family defined within a typeclass and it seems `DeriveDataTypeable` chokes on this. Or I may misinterpreting the compiler errors

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I rewrite that type to allow to extract logPayload if I know its type?

If you do not want to change your type, you can replace `fromJSON & toJSON` by `unsafeCoerce` – same idea, same result if you are right, but might crash your program if you are not right about the type.

If you want the type checker to ensure that you are right, you will have to expose the type `a` in `LogEvent` and not use an existential type.